# How can I specify additional arguments for use with CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY variable

Tags: cmake, clang-static-analyzer, clang-tidy

I'm trying to use make use of [clang-tidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy) integration with [cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/variable/CMAKE_LANG_CLANG_TIDY.html) and I'd like to pass the `-check` argument. I've tried adding `-DCMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY="/usr/local/opt/llvm38/bin/clang-tidy-3.8;-checks=*"` when invoking cmake, but my makefile commands end-up looking like:

`/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.6.2/bin/cmake -E __run_iwyu --tidy="/usr/local/opt/llvm38/bin/clang-tidy-3.8;-checks=*" --source=/Users/ellery/work/.....`

in other words, it seems like the ; separated args are not being parsed apart. I've also tried setting the target property `CXX_CLANG_TIDY` directly on my target with the same value and I get the same behavior.

Has anyone succesfully invoked `clang-tidy` with additional args through cmake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works as expected with cmake 3.7.2 and clang-tidy 4.0.

E.g. directly specifying on the command line:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY="clang-tidy;-style=file;-checks=*"
```

or in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "clang-tidy;-style=file;-checks=*")
```

You have to make sure that the `clang-tidy` arguments are correct, otherwise it seems to fail silently.

Comment: clang-tidy Unknown command line argument '-style=file', but ok when cut off '-style=file'.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct. CMake does not parse those arguments when generating the makefile, but when the makefile is **executed**. When a file was successful compiled, then clang-tidy will be executed automatically.

You could try setting CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY directly in your CMakeLists.txt:
`set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "clang-tidy" "-checks=*")`

Comment: hmmm - that's interesting. When I set this in my cmake file, I fail almost immediately with:

`Error running '/usr/local/opt/llvm38/bin/clang-tidy-3.8`. There are no more details about the failure, however.  If I leave off the "-checks=*" argument, the build seems to succeed, but I get the (presumably) default behavior of clang-tidy.